# check if specific li element exists in ul

Tags: javascript

I've got a script that adds li elements to a ul and assigns some attributes to it based on a user's selection in a select element.  However, I figured it would be necessary to make sure that the li element doesn't already exist in the ul.  However, I'm not sure, but I think that either the array isn't assigning variables to it or there's something wrong with my if statement that compares the array.  Of course, I may be totally off.  I'm stumped.

```
function anotherCounty(){    
  var newCounty = document.forms['newForm'].county.value;
  var ul = document.getElementById("counties"); 
  var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var itemArray = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    itemArray.push(items[i]);
  }

  if (itemArray.indexOf(newCounty)<'0'){//I've also tried ==-1 and <0
    var new_item = document.createElement("li");
    new_item.id = "addCounty[]";
    new_item.innerHTML = newCounty;
    ul.insertBefore(new_item, ul.firstChild);
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a string with DOM elements. I think this is what you actually need:

```
itemArray.push(items[i].value);
```

Comment: This and the other strategy both makes a lot of sense.  But, for some reason they are not working.  I can't believe I hadn't added the value attribute.  Thanks for pointing that out at least.

Comment: Maybe you should create a live demo, for example on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using indexOf, you'd be a lot better off to use this approach:

```
function anotherCounty() {

    var newCounty = document.forms['newForm'].county.value;
    var ul = document.getElementById("counties");   
    var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        if(items[i].value == newCounty) return;
    }

    var new_item = document.createElement("li");
    new_item.id = "addCounty[]";
    new_item.innerHTML = newCounty;
    ul.insertBefore(new_item, ul.firstChild);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but I just had the same issue and what worked for me was

```
itemArray.push(items[i].innerHTML);
```